# Light Photons 101

Tags: particle-physics

How are photons emitted from: for example a heated metal. Are they smaller than electrons, do they collide with electrons or can you even say microwaves are made of photons?

Comment: Neither photons nor electrons are little hard spheres, they are quantum particles, and colliding for them means to interact. The thermal radiation is present inside all of the heated body (as it is an equilibrium property) and in a dynamic equilibrium of emission and absorption with the electrons. But on the surface of (say a metal) the photons can escape, because there are no more electrons to reabsorb them outside (and the free path length of photons in a metal will be on the scale of a few nm, so some photons will reach the surface and be emitted from there).

Comment: Hello. You should re-phrase you question if you have some time. I don't think it's clear what you are asking or how many questions you are asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Photons or electrons can both be thought of as waves or particles and they interact via quantum fields.

However what I think your looking for is to do with emission and absorption. When materials, like metals you describe in your question, absorb photons, the demoralised electrons in these metals absorb all the energy from those photons. Because of this the electrons will go up in energy levels- (this is to do with how electrons are organised into shells).

Eventually the electrons will emit this extra energy they gained, releasing it from the material as photons; the electrons will revert to their original energy levels. Also the type of photon: microwave, radio waves,  gamma ray, infant red etc... all depends on how much energy the material absorbed. If it absorbed a lot of energy/photons, then it will have to emit just as much- so the photons emitted will be high energy like gamma rays. Likewise low absorption means low energy photons are emitted like microwaves or radio waves.

I recommend you familiarise yourself with the electromagnetic spectrum.